# AgGrid custom TIME filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, ag-grid

In ag-grid i only found custom date filter but couldn't find anything for filtering just time. Can someone please help me how to do custom filter just for time. I have column data format like hh:mm. I need to give the user the privilege to filter time.

Am using angularJs with the free version of ag-grid.

Answer (score 2):

As of now, ag-grid doesn't provide a time filter.
You will have to write your own custom time filter using `FilterInterface` or if you are using Angular then implementing `AgFilterComponent`.

Here's an excellent example on the ag-grid site [Custom Filter Component](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-component/)